# SQL Selection Based on html input

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

How can I write SQL query based on what the user select on the html interface?
For example

```
id     |    acc_type       |     bill_charge  |  Month   |  Year
_________________________________________________________________
1      |        store      |         12       |  January |  2014     
2      |     water plant   |         11       |  January |  2013
3      |       store       |         51       |  February|  2014
4      |      pump house   |         34       |  March   |  2014
4      |      pump house   |         33       |  January |  2014
4      |      pump house   |          5       |  January |  2014
4      |      pump house   |         22       |  March   |  2013
4      |      pump house   |          0       |  March   |  2014
```

And the user will be in charge of what months and year to view the data
Right now the only thing that i can figure is redirect to different php file that will have QUERY for EVERY single month and in that particular month EVERY single year from 2014-2020 like this:

```
SELECT id , acc_type , bill_charge , month , year
FROM   acc_info , acc_details , acc_bill
WHERE  acc_info.id = acc_details.id  AND Month ="January" AND Year = "2014"
```

And the user will be selecting from this input

```
<select name="Month" id="Month" width="300px" required/>
<option value="">--Select Month--</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>


<select  name="Year" id="Year" width="300px" required/>
<option value="">--Select Year--</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the values to a PHP script through a form. First, define the form:

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
<select name="Month" id="Month" width="300px" required/>
<option value="">--Select Month--</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select  name="Year" id="Year" width="300px" required/>
<option value="">--Select Year--</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
</form>
```

After defining the form, you write a PHP script that parses the incoming values, connects to the database and send the request. For example like this:

```
<?php
$Month = $_REQUEST["Month"];
$Year = $_REQUEST["Year"];

// Database example from PHP.net manual
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id , acc_type , bill_charge , month , year
                              FROM   acc_info , acc_details , acc_bill
                              WHERE  acc_info.id = acc_details.id  AND Month ='".$Month."' AND Year = '".$Year."'")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Please consider reading the PHP + MySQL manual, either through MySQLi (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

P.S. Please note that using code like `$Month = $_REQUEST["Month"]` might actually be unsafe and lead to an SQL injection. More on this please read this article: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

**UPDATE**

If you're willing to output the data, you may do it like this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id , acc_type , bill_charge , month , year
                              FROM   acc_info , acc_details , acc_bill
                              WHERE  acc_info.id = acc_details.id  AND Month ='".$Month."' AND Year = '".$Year."'")) {
    while($output = $result->fetch_assoc) {
        echo $output['id']." ".$output['acc_type']." ".$output['bill_charge']." ".$output['month']." ".$output['year']."<br>";
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: This may sound silly, but how can i call the data into a page where there's table to present the data? do i link the that page inside "script.php" or just combine it altogether?

Comment: @itsfawwaz I have updated my answer with an example of how to output the data.

Comment: @itsfawwaz I think the code I wrote is self-explanatory enough. Please read the code, read on basics of OOP and you will see the answer in my code.

Answer (score -1):

User should select a date, such as January which then can be concatted into `2014-01-01` and the SQL query can search the date range of the data input.  (You should always have `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps for data in your database.)